# Why T::class.java is Class<out Int> in Kotlin?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I define a class,It like this

```
class ResponseHandler<T : Any>(
    val typeClass: Class<out Int> = T::class.java,
    val start: () -> Unit = {},
    val success: (result: SuccessInfo<T>) -> Unit,
    val complete: () -> Unit = {}){/*...*/}
```

but why type of [T::class.java] is

```
   Class<out Int>
```

What  i should do if i want to get the class of T ?

for example:

```
ResponseHandler<User>(....).typeClass is User,not Int.
```

Comment: Try `<out T>` maybe?

Comment: @Sweeper   
Change val typeClass: Class<out Int> = T::class.java to
val typeClass: Class<out T> = T::class.java,???

Comment: note that I don't know kotlin, it's just what my instincts say. If that didn't work, try just <T>.

Comment: Had the same issue and somwhow found out that I had a weird import "android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T" in my class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get class of generic `T`:

- Kotlin way: [Kotlin reified parameters feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).
- Java way: use `extension` mechanism like Jackson does in it's [TypeRefference class](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html)